# Clarify the tense with 'Since'

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence in correct:

We sell and repair sewing machines since 1974.
OR
Selling and repairing sewing machines, since 1974.

Kindly clarify.

Comment: They're both wrong.  The first cries out for the present perfect tense, while the second is a participial phrase and not a complete, correct sentence.  The second sentence also has a spurious comma.

Comment: The first is ungrammatical (thus unacceptable); the second is a sentence fragment (acceptable in certain contexts, but usually without the comma).

Comment: One valid construction which can be created largely by combining elements from both the (invalid) examples above would be *We **have been selling and repairing** sewing machines since 1974*. But this strikes me as essentially proofreading.

Comment: So, if I am writing second sentence without comma then it would be correct?

Comment: Please [edit] to add some context, such as whether this is for something like a cornerstone plaque or it is to be a sentence in a piece of prose.